# Form Validation Errors in Bootstrap/Flask to highlight field in red

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-5, flask-wtforms

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here. I am trying to get the fields in this registration form to highlight red if there is an error and display the error. However, when I submit a blank form it prompts a pop up instead. Anyone have any suggestions what could be going on with this code?

```
{%extends 'layouts.html'%}

{%block content%}
<div class="container w-50">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {{form.hidden_tag()}}

        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Register User</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.username.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.username.errors%}
                {{form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.username.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.username(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.firstName.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.firstName.errors%}
                    {{form.firstName(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.firstName.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.firstName(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.lastName.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.lastName.errors%}
                    {{form.lastName(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.lastName.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.lastName(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.password.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.password.errors%}
                    {{form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.password.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.password(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.confirmPassword.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.confirmPassword.errors%}
                    {{form.confirmPassword(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.confirmPassword.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.confirmPassword(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.emailAddress.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.emailAddress.errors%}
                    {{form.emailAddress(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.emailAddress.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.emailAddress(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.managerID.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.managerID.errors%}
                    {{form.managerID(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.managerID.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.managerID(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{form.roleID.label(class="form-control-label")}}
                {%if form.roleID.errors%}
                    {{form.roleID(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid")}}
                    {%for error in form.roleID.errors%}
                        <span>{{error}}</span>
                    {%endfor%}
                {%else%}
                    {{form.roleID(class="form-control form-control-lg")}}
                {%endif%}

            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <div class="field-group">
            {{form.submit(class='btn btn-online-info')}}
            
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8stY.png)

[Output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG8l2.png)

I've gone through and reviewed my script against the tutorial I'm following. I also added a is-invalid function in my css file

```
/* Style for invalid form controls */
.is-invalid {
    border: 1px solid #dc3545; /* Red border */
    color: #dc3545; /* Red text color */
  }
```

I cannot identify why this is happening.